# Copy/Paste from Excel Workbook (on Sharepoint) to Another (On Desktop) using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, scheduled-tasks, vba

I am trying to use Task Scheduler to run a Powershell script (below) that copies a range of cells from an Excel file (hosted on a Sharepoint site) and pastes that range into another Excel workbook (on my desktop) every morning.

This is just a step in a long process that I have figured out, except for this last piece!

Any insight?

```
#This opens a new Excel object and makes it visible
$excel=new-object -comobject excel.application;
$excel.visible=$true;

#This identifies the source workbook (the one from which the data will be copied).
$SourceWorkBook=$Excel.Workbooks.open("\\sites\DavWWWRoot\RM\data\MS Reports\PathName");

#This identifies the target workbook (the one to which the data will be pasted)
$TargetWorkBook=$excel.workBooks.Open("\\rmhso-ss1\HSO-Share\Team folders\Accounting Team\Matt\Reporting\NewDailySales\Test.xlsx");

#This activates the source workbook
$SourceWorkBook.WorkSheets.item("Daily Sales - Current Week").activate();

#This specifies the range that we want to copy
$SourceRange=$SourceWorkBook.WorkSheets.item("Daily Sales - Current Week").range("A8:BI1200");

#This copies that range. It will say "true" if the copy is successful, but we're not interested in seeing that.
#Because of this, we will use the out-null cmdlet, which discards any info that is piped to it.
$SourceRange.copy() | out-null;

#This identifies the destination where we want the information copied.
#Here, it pastes the information in the tab named "Sheet2" of the target workbook
#First, identify where you want it pasted
$TargetRange=$TargetWorkbook.Worksheets.item("Sheet2").range("L90:BT1200");

#Then, paste that into the target workbook
$TargetWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Paste($TargetRange);
```

Comment: What does your script do?  By this I mean, does it copy some or all of the stuff successfully, and does it paste?  Or are you getting an error?  If so where?  Also, have you considered having the Target sheet reference the source sheet directly?  Then you could simplify by having the task copy the source spreadsheet to a known location, with a consistent name, and having the target sheet refer to that name.

Comment: I think this should be as simple as replacing the last line with `$TargetRange.Activate()|Out-Null; $Excel.ActiveSheet.Paste()`

Comment: Oh wow - yes, it was a simple as changing the last line as @TheMadTechnician suggested. Much appreciated!